# eval does not work, but JSON.parse does

Tags: javascript, eval

I have a string returned from the server. It is of the format,

```
[{"text":"content"}]
```

where `content` is a dynamic string and will vary based on user actions. In one such particular case, the returned string cannot be eval'ed, but when I use `JSON.parse`, it works fine without issues. My eval is like below

```
eval("(" + response + ")").
```

Due to certain restrictions I cannot paste the problematic string here. But are there any particular cases where `eval` will not work and `JSON.parse` will work?

**EDIT1 :**
I narrowed down the problem and the particular string which gives the problem is,

```
[{"con" :"g <\/font><\/td"}]
```

This string cannot be eval'ed but can by parsed.
I guess the issue is because of the sting"/". But I am not able to understand why. Any help in this regard will be great.

**EDIT2:**
There exists an invisible character between g and < and that is causing the issue. Does anyone know what character it is?
I will be changing the eval to JSON.parse. But I wanted to know the reason why it failed.

Comment: Why do you want to use `eval`?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `'[{"text":"content"}]'` instead of `"[{"text":"content"}]"`?

Comment: Why exactly can't you paste the JSON string here? Just remove any personal data etc. @Oriol: I think we can safely assume that the outer quotes are not in his actual code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That buggy character is U+8232, the [Unicode `LINE SEPARATOR`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_control_characters#Unicode_introduced_separators). It leads to "unterminated string literal" syntax errors in various browsers, this is why it does not work to `eval()` the string. `JSON.parse` can work around that, as [JSON is not really a JS subset](http://timelessrepo.com/json-isnt-a-javascript-subset) in that perspective.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [json2 library](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) to parse your JSON.

Comment: +1 (Although this library is simply a polyfill in case the JSON object and its methods aren't available)

Answer (score -1):

You are confusing parsing JSON and parsing JavaScript. `eval()` does not parse JSON.
Eval would require valid JS syntax.
In `"test":"test"`, the quotes around the property are not valid in javascript object literal notation

Comment: `the quotes around the property are not valid in javascript object literal notation`.  Uhhh, yes they are.  `var obj = {"test":"Test"}` works just fine.